# Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DATA_INVALID

Tags: java, pkcs#11

I'm having problems with my application that generates xml signed, but just happen it on Windows, I don't have the problem on Linux, proves with jre 7 and jre 8 thanks advance.

```
    java.security.ProviderException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: E

    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineSign(P11Signature.java:547)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Signature.sign(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.implementations.SignatureBaseRSA.engineSign(SignatureBaseRSA.java:130)
    at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm.sign(SignatureAlgorithm.java:173)
    at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.sign(XMLSignature.java:614)
    at bo.accl.clientelynx.Signer.firmar(Signer.java:283)
    at bo.accl.clientelynx.Signer.sign(Signer.java:168)
    at bo.accl.clientelynx.Signer.apply(Signer.java:350)
    at bo.accl.clientelynx.Signer.apply(Signer.java:61)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:860)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at bo.accl.clientelynx.App$17.doInBackground(App.java:1130)
    at bo.accl.clientelynx.App$17.doInBackground(App.java:1095)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DATA_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Sign(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineSign(P11Signature.java:538)
```

Comment: Please, give us more details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

After searching on CKR_DATA_INVALID I found that the error is:

> The plaintext input data to a cryptographic operation is invalid.
>   This return value has lower priority than CKR_DATA_LEN_RANGE.

See: http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/pkcs11__all_8h.html#aCKR_DATA_INVALID

My guest is you have an encoding problem with your data between windows and Linux. Check your data file to find invalid windows characters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the data file has numbers and dates only, the problem started when I changed the Algorithm sha1 to sha256.

Comment: What is the length of the key? If you were using a _very short_ key, you _might_ encounter a similar problem. Did you try with at least 1024 bit key? (I assume you are using RSA)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem while I was working with an older version of the p11-capi library. In my case I wanted to use a new signature algorithm (SHA256withRSA instead of SHA1withRSA) and received the same Java exception. The exception is not very helpful, so it took quite long until I found out that the problem has been fixed in the recent library version: https://risacher.org/p11-capi/

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is facing the CKR_FUNCTION_FAILED under provider exception,then kindly check whether alias name is proper .if there are multiple alias then check one by one in keystore.